# Adding corresponding Numbers in a Range

Tags: sed, awk

I have a dataset with 30000 lines. I want to add all the corresponding values (i.e. Column 2)  between the range 0-50 and then 50.1-100 and then 100.1-150 etc. (presented in column 1), and this sequence goes on for the rest of the lines in the file.

**Input File:**

```
10         1
21.1       1
22         1
28         2
30         5
44.44      2
44.45      1
50         2
55         22
100.11     200
105        5
600.2      10
888        90
```

**Expected Output:**

```
0          15
50         22
100        205
600        10
850        90
```

I tried

```
awk     'NR==1          {printf "%s\t",$1; N=$1+49}
     $1>=N          {printf "%s\n%s\t",sum,N; N+=49; sum=0}
                    {sum+=$2}
     END            {printf "%s\n", sum}
    ' myfile
```

But I am not getting the expected output.

Comment: What is the highest number you can have? I take it the values in column1 are arbitrary?

Comment: In Column 1, I select the 50 consecutive numbers. I start with 0-50 and add all the corresponding numbers in column2 ranging in this group. Then 50.1-100 then 100.1-150, then 150.1-200, then 200.1-250 so on and so forth.  It highest number I have in Column 1 in my original data set is  8709.97.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
$ awk '
 {arr[int(($1%50?$1:($1-1))/50)]+=$2};
 END{for(k in arr){print k*50, arr[k]}}
' file.txt | sort -k1,1n
```

#### Example

You can control the format of the output using `printf` within `awk` too.

```
$ awk '
 {arr[int(($1%50?$1:($1-1))/50)]+=$2};
 END{for(k in arr){printf "%-11s%-5s\n", k*50, arr[k]}}
' file.txt | sort -k1,1n
0          15   
50         22   
100        205  
600        10   
850        90
```

Comment: Nice, +1 especially since your solution does not require sorting the file as mine does.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
sort -g file | awk 'BEGIN{N=50}{
    if($1<=N){out[N-50]+=$2}
    else{while($1>=N){N+=50;}; 
         out[N-50]+=$2}
    }END{for(i in out){print i,out[i]} }' | sort -g
```